# ASP.Net, Datagrid: render column differently based upon value?

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

I've looked and looked and I'm not seeing the answer to this.

I have a datetime value that's getting bound to a datagrid.  I want to display the column as either the datetime, or if said datetime is null, an asp:button for the users to click.

I can't seem to find specific information on how to do it.  My initial approach was <% if blah blah then %>, but I can't seem to get *at* the dataitem in that manner.  I've also looked at events, but nothing is jumping out at me as being the solution (I'm sure I'm wrong, I'm just not seeing it).

Any suggestions?

Comment: DataGrid is ASP.NET 1.1 control, maybe you can solve your problems using GridView http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05yye6k9.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you actually mean `GridView` instead of `DataGrid`, otherwise it would work similarly(`ItemDataBound` etc.).

You could use a [`TemplateField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx) with a `Label` and a `Button` and switch visibility of both controls in [`RowDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx):

```
protected void Grid_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        DateTime? date = row.Field<DateTime?>("DateColumn");
        var lblDate = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("LblDate");
        var btnDate = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("BtnDate");
        lblDate.Visible = date.HasValue;
        btnDate.Visible = !date.HasValue;
        if (date.HasValue) lblDate.Text = date.ToString();
    }
}
```

aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="Grid_RowDataBound" runat="server">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DateColumn">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="LblDate" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Button ID="BtnDate" Text="click me" runat="server"  />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Slow reply due to the easter holidays, sorry about that.  This was perfect, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use Gridview if you are using ASP.NET 3.5 or higher. Using a templatefield column, add a button and label. In the rowdatabound event, you should show only the button or the label, using the Visible property, depending on whether there's a date or not.

Comment: GridView exists in ASP.NET 2.0 too